# Replacing within brackets and word after brackets with regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I have the following text:

```
text_to_transform = "... sistema solar número 90377;[7]\u200b[n. 3]\u200b concretamente ..."
```

I am using regex to replace the pattern `[number]\u200b` and `[n. number ]\u200b`. Notice that in this example they happen one after the other but this is not necessarily true in the data.

This is my attempt but for some reason it's not picking it up.

```
re.sub(r'\[[^)]*\]\\u200b', '', text_to_transform)
```

Comment: You need to remove one backslash from `\\u`: `re.sub(r'\[[^]]*\]\u200b', '', text_to_transform)`. Also, I think you wanted to use `[^]]` instead of `[^)]` (to stay within `[...]`). Your string contains literal ZERO WIDTH SPACEs, while the regex is looking for ``\`` followed with `u200b` substring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match the zero width spaces with `r'\u200b'`. Your regex is looking for `\` followed with `u200b` substring instead, with `r'\\u200b'`.

See the Python 3 demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> text_to_transform = "... sistema solar número 90377;[7]\u200b[n. 3]\u200b concretamente ..."
>>> res = re.sub(r'\[[^]]*\]\u200b', '', text_to_transform)
>>> print(res)
... sistema solar número 90377; concretamente ...
>>>
```

Also, note that `\[[^]]*\]` matches `[`, then 0+ chars other than **`]`** and then `]`, while you regex matches `[`, then 0+ chars other than **`)`** and then `]`, i.e. it can match across `[` and `]`.